# How to select an element in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, select

I tried:

```
try { Thread.sleep (1000); } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}    


        
        WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("select2-cadastrar_veiculos_combustivel-container"));
        dropdown.click();
        List<WebElement> options = dropdown.findElements(By.id("select2-cadastrar_veiculos_combustivel-result-lbmm-DIESEL"));
        System.out.println(options);
        
         try { Thread.sleep (60000); } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
```

But don't work. Show: Expected Select but was a span class.

The html code.

```html
.<span class="select2-dropdown select2-dropdown--below" dir="ltr" style="width: 188.5px;"><span class="select2-search select2-search--dropdown select2-search--hide"><input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" role="textbox"></span><span class="select2-results"><ul class="select2-results__options" role="tree" id="select2-cadastrar_veiculos_combustivel-results" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false"><li class="select2-results__option select2-results__option--highlighted" id="select2-cadastrar_veiculos_combustivel-result-kada--1" role="treeitem" aria-selected="true" data-select2-id="select2-cadastrar_veiculos_combustivel-result-kada--1"><span><i class="undefined"></i> &nbsp;</span></li><li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-cadastrar_veiculos_combustivel-result-aq67-DIESEL" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" data-select2-id="select2-cadastrar_veiculos_combustivel-result-aq67-DIESEL"><span><i class="undefined"></i> 
                                            DIESEL                                      </span></li><li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-cadastrar_veiculos_combustivel-result-kvyg-ETANOL" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" data-select2-id="select2-cadastrar_veiculos_combustivel-result-kvyg-ETANOL"><span><i class="undefined"></i> 
                                            ETANOL                                      </span></li><li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-cadastrar_veiculos_combustivel-result-zrmr-FLEX" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" data-select2-id="select2-cadastrar_veiculos_combustivel-result-zrmr-FLEX"><span><i class="undefined"></i> 
                                            FLEX                                        </span></li><li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-cadastrar_veiculos_combustivel-result-v7yw-GASOLINA" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" data-select2-id="select2-cadastrar_veiculos_combustivel-result-v7yw-GASOLINA"><span><i class="undefined"></i> 
                                            GASOLINA                                        </span></li><li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-cadastrar_veiculos_combustivel-result-gv8q-GNV" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" data-select2-id="select2-cadastrar_veiculos_combustivel-result-gv8q-GNV"><span><i class="undefined"></i> 
                                            GNV                                     </span></li></ul></span></span>
```

If I put:

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("select2-cadastrar_veiculos_combustivel-container"))).selectByVisibleText("DIESEL");
```

Comment: That's not a Select tag. You can click on the element  and then click on the element you need.

Comment: Not works.

Do you can help with the code?